# Separate text in Java with backslash-zero as delimiter

Tags: java, escaping, character, tokenize

Suppose I have a binary file that has this content:

```
abc\0def\0ghi\0
```

The content is already read and stored in a string variable s. How should I extract the components "abc", "def", "ghi" into different string tokens? The usual methods such as split, stringTokenizer do not accept `\0` as delimiter.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`\0` is the [null character](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_character), so you can use its unicode representation as a delimiter.

```
String content = "abc\0def\0ghi\0";
String[] components = content.split("\u0000");
```

However, you *can* use just "\0" as the delimiter to split on.

Comment: I don't think that would work: *"Illegal octal escape sequence near index 2: \0"*

Comment: I think the original string is `"abc\\0def\\0ghi\\0"` - the string that the OP shows is what is in the file. I might have misunderstood.

Comment: @assylias I think you might have; the null character is a common delimiter in files, so it's logical to assume that the file has "\0"s than "\\0"s.

Comment: @Vulcan you were right ;-) Note that `content.split("\0")` would work too.

Comment: @assylias Nice point out, it didn't even come to mind to try that because OP said it didn't work.  I'll add that to the answer, thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

If the original String is `"abc\\0def\\0ghi\\0"` then you can use `split("\\\\0")`:

```
"abc\\0def\\0ghi\\0".split("\\\\0")
```

If the original String is `"abc\0def\0ghi\0"` then you can use `split("\0")`:

```
"abc\0def\0ghi\0".split("\0")
```

Comment: Cause it's perfectly natural to choose a backslash-followed-by-a-zero as a delimiter.